On the form of algebraic numbers belonging to a specific field extension
Let $m>1$ be an integer and set $\theta=10^{-1/m}$. For a $\gamma\in \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, there exists $a_0,\ldots,a_{m-1}\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
\gamma=a_0+a_1\theta+\cdots+a_{m-1}\theta^{m-1}.
$$
Claim: Suppose that $\gamma$ has degree $k<m$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I would like to prove that $a_j=0$ whenever $d:=m/k$ does not divide $j$.
I know that both $\gamma$ and $\theta^d$ are $k$-degree algebraic numbers and, probably, the condition $\gamma\in \mathbb{Q}(\theta^d)$ finishes the proof.
However, I was not able to prove the claim in any case.
Any suggestions?

It would be enough to prove $\mathbb Q(\gamma)=\mathbb Q(10^{-1/k})$. You should be able to do it with Galois theory - look at the subgroups of $Gal(\mathbb Q(\theta,\zeta_m),\mathbb Q)\cong(\mathbb Z/m)\rtimes(\mathbb Z/m)^\times$ containing $Gal(\mathbb Q(\theta,\zeta_m),\mathbb Q(\theta)\cong(\mathbb Z/m)^\times$, and check there is only one of each index dividing $m$.

@Wojowu Thanks for your answer, however I am not so familiar to Galois Theory to prove this. Could you please provide me a little more details and I will work to prove it.
